# Mapa parou de aparecer ao mudar de PC

Tags: android

Eu tenho um mapa em um fragment que estava funcionando normalmente até eu tentar rodar em outro PC. Passei tudo por Pen Drive e ao tentar rodar o mapa não aparece e no logcat diz que a autorização falhou.

Fragment

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProvider;
MapView mMapView;
GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_estacionar, container, false);

    mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

    mFusedLocationProvider = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap = mMap;

            googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
                return;
            } else {
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                mFusedLocationProvider.getLastLocation()
                        .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                                if (location != null) {
                                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

                                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                            .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                                            .zoom(14)                   // Sets the zoom
                                            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
                                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                                }
                            }
                        });

            }

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

XML do Fragment

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns:sndroid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/root_estacionar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     tools:context="meuapp.Fragment">


     <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
         android:id="@+id/mapView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:focusable="true">

     </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para quem tiver o mesmo problema...

Era um problema com a API key. Eu gerei de um PC e ela funcionava ao rodar dele, depois eu gerei outra chave do PC dando problema e funcionou. Esou escrevendo para ajudar alguém e para, se essa não foi a melhor solução, alguém me ajudar. E por favor, se alguém souber porque isso aconteceu diz aí =)